# Specifying Grid column and row definition by style in resource

Tags: wpf, xaml

There is an UserControl with the following Grid:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

Now I have a Window and there are I would to write something like that:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Grid">
        <Setter Property="RowDefinitions">
            <Value>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

The key part, which doesn't compile is when I want to change Height from Auto to *. How to do this in legal way?

In general I have to cases. 1) The first row should stretch and the second should be fixed. 2) Vice versa. Maybe a different panel than Grid could be more relevant?

Comment: your code doesn't compile, because of the following error `The Property Setter 'RowDefinitions' cannot be set because it does not have an accessible set accessor.`
not sure what exactly you are trying to do but styles were created to describe how visual objects will look like while the RowDefenition defines the visual tree itself.

Comment: @makc The problem is how to get around this limitation?

Comment: don't define RowDefinitions inside a style, just create another grid and change the visibility properties or use code behind, but again you should try describing what you are really trying to achieve...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Grid.RowDefinitions` and `Grid.ColumnDefinitions` are no dependency properties, and can't hence be set by a Style.

You may perhaps create a dependency property `FirstRowHeight` in your UserControl, and bind the `Height` of the first `RowDefinition` to that property. Later you may set the `FirstRowHeight` property in a `Style`.

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="{Binding FirstRowHeight,
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
    <RowDefinition/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

The property would look like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty FirstRowHeightProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "FirstRowHeight", typeof(GridLength), typeof(YourUserControl));

public GridLength FirstRowHeight
{
    get { return (GridLength)GetValue(FirstRowHeightProperty); }
    set { SetValue(FirstRowHeightProperty, value); }
}
```

---

EDIT: In order to support the simple scenario you describe at the end of your question, you may also just have an `IsFirstRowFixed` dependency property with a property changed callback that sets the row heights in code:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition x:Name="row1" Height="*"/>
    <RowDefinition x:Name="row2" Height="Auto"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

The property:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsFirstRowFixedProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "IsFirstRowFixed", typeof(bool), typeof(UserControl2),
        new PropertyMetadata((o, e) => ((UserControl2)o).IsFirstRowFixedChanged()));

public bool IsFirstRowFixed
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(IsFirstRowFixedProperty); }
    set { SetValue(IsFirstRowFixedProperty, value); }
}

private void IsFirstRowFixedChanged()
{
    if (IsFirstRowFixed)
    {
        row1.Height = GridLength.Auto;
        row2.Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
    }
    else
    {
        row1.Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
        row2.Height = GridLength.Auto;
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Quite complex, but it is exactly what I needed :)

Comment: You may perhaps also get something similar by using a DockPanel instead of the Grid, and change the children order in code behind in order to let the last child fill the remaining space. That might however become even more complex than this.

Comment: That could be another answer for another +1

Answer (score 0):

**XAML code :**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource HeaderHeight}"</>
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource FooterHeight}"</>
</>
```

**Styles in Resource dictionary**

```
<Style TargetType="Frame" x:Name="HeaderHeight">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="700"></Setter>
</Style>
<Style TargetType="Grid" x:Name="FooterHeight">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="70"></Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.