# WPF - Set font size of a row

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf

I'm looking for some elegant way to set `fontSize` for all elements in a row. Unfortunately, code

```
<RowDefinition Height="40" fontSize ="20" />
```

do not work.

Comment: Maybe this will be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39409365/how-to-change-the-font-size-of-all-text-box-within-a-grid-windows-app-uwp

Comment: @SlavenHvar yes, this might work. I'll test it, thanks!

Comment: Well, it looks like I'm trying to do impossible https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922487/specifying-grid-column-and-row-definition-by-style-in-resource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set the `FontSize` property of a `RowDefinition`. The best you can do is to set the `FontSize` property of the root element of the row, e.g.:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- row 1 -->
    <TextBlock Text="1" />

    <!-- row 2 -->
    <StackPanel TextElement.FontSize="40" Grid.Row="1">
        <TextBlock>2</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>3</TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>

    <!-- row 3 -->
    <TextBlock Text="4" Grid.Row="2" />
</Grid>
```